# How do I automatically relocate 10k Lightroom photos that only exist in "ghost folders?"

Tags: lightroom, file-management

I have a large Lightroom catalog containing ~20k culled and edited photos. Each set of related photos (usually around 50-200 photos) exists in a parent folder, which I'll call the "event folder."

Over the years I have reorganized a lot of my file layouts, moving around a lot of event folders (although I've kept individual photos in their respective folders).

However, I'm having a strange issue with around 10k of the photos in my Lightroom catalog. Take this set of 72 photos which originally used to be in an event folder called `2018-05-10`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Clearly, LR is aware that all the photos were originally together in the same folder. However, when I try to view the event folder in the Library in the left sidebar (right click > Go to Folder in Library), nothing shows up in the sidebar! So this event folder seems to be a "ghost folder" which LR recognized but doesn't show in the Library.

This leads to a major complication. When I manually "locate" one of the missing photos, it doesn't locate the remaining photos in the ghost folder, even though the "Find Nearby Missing Photos" option is checked. Only the photo that was just located disappears into the updated folder in the library, leaving behind the other 71 photos.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Since there are around 10k photos existing in these "ghost folders," how do I relocate them without having to manually go through every single photo?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by right clicking > Show Folder in Library, and then restarting the Lightroom catalog. It would show a new set of folders that didn't show up before. I kept doing this for the remaining photos and they quickly all started showing up for me.